# Multiple accounts running the same trigger on edit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

What would happen if 2 gmail accounts, for example account one@gmail.com and account two@gmail.com, were to have triggers set to run the same script on a google sheet each time the spreadsheet was edited.  Would it run the script twice? Once for one account and then again for the other right after each other? Does it check if one is the owner and only run the owners script?

Answer (score 1):

It would run both scripts at the same time (in separate threads).

Comment: Is there any way to prevent this (only allow the owner to run the code) ?

Comment: You could add code in the script to store the email of the first user to run it, and then in future on run the code for that user...